# fitsSystemWindows ignored by ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout, android-statusbar

I am trying to show make an activity in my app where the statusbar is completely transparent. I added this to my style:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

But for some reason all views in my are all appearing below the statusbar. All the views are top aligned to parent `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following code to my activity:

```
Window w = getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Comment: This only works in your case because you want the navigation bar transparent as well. If somebody only wants the status bar to be transparent, it won't work for them.

Answer (score 2):

Since I wanted to show my layout behind the status bar but still keep the navigation bar the same, this is what worked for me:

Add `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` to my activity theme

Since `ConstraintLayout` does not seem to respect `fitsSystemWindows`, wrap it in a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my `CoordinatorLayout`.
Add to my `ConstraintLayout`

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
```

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is actually respected by `ConstraintsLayout`. Wrapping the `ConstraintLayout` with a `CoordinatorLayout` isn't needed.

Comment: Also, if you only added `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` and not `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`, you don't even have to added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Well, this is what worked for me. I'll add my full theme config later!

Comment: Yeah. This would work but what I'm saying is that you added way more than what you needed. The comment was for everyone else who'll take a look at this post in the future.

Comment: Well, after your comment I went ahead and removed the CoordinatorLayout, but I can't make it work that way. ConstraintLayout doesn't stretch under the status bar.